# Recommended Aconcagua Guide Source?

Tags: mountaineering

Anyone know a good method of finding Aconcagua guides that will work with a pair solo outside of an organised group? Most guides I've seen online so far take groups & use a lot of porters. We're really only after a guide who will work with ourselves for the duration.

Online the main search results are fixed party numbers only and quite structured.

We are experienced to 5000m, we're fit and looking to do it in good time (~10days).

Comment: I think this question is perfectly fine for TGO, it's very interesting in my opinion. It is about organizing a mountain tour while the infos given here might not be subjective at all and they might be very helpful for planning tours on other mountains too.

Comment: Interesting question. I'd like to know the answer. I know someone who knows someone who did it completely unsupported, I believe as a group of 2, but that required some serious logistics and planning. Isn't hiring a guide for 10 days going to be pretty expensive, if you're only splitting the cost two ways?

Answer (score 6):

I would look for a club or group of climbers, not a business, and see if they want to go with you. As long as you are willing to cover transportation, you'll probably find people who'll take you, and probably new friends.

I've belonged to a climbing club in Peru and we did that a couple of times.